# Cards, bags and coins recurrence relation understanding

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum, recurrence

https://www.codechef.com/problems/ANUCBC basically boils down to below:

Given an array A of n integers and a positive integer m (1<=m<=100), find the number of subsets of this array which are divisible by m.

Recurrence relation: 
Let dp[i][j] represent the number of subsets containing elements upto the ith element in array and whose sum of elements when divided my m gives remainder j.

dp(i,j) = dp(i-1,j) + dp(i-1,(j-a[i])%m)

However, I am not able to understand j-a[i] part. Let me explain clearly why I am stuck with a example.

[6, 7, 7] and m=5

Suppose, we are at index 0: here all we need is to know if the number is divisible by 5 or not. If not, just know what mod it returns and remember that.

dp[0][1] should be true as it leaves a remainder (6%5) of 1.

Same goes for index 1: dp[1][2] will be true as 7%5=2. We also somehow need to know record dp[1][3] as true as adding (6+7)%5 = 3.

However, at index 2 we need to know past result dp[1][3] in order for it to note dp[2][0] as true because (3+2)%5 is 0.

Can anyone help me understanding this, I have spent countless hours on this without much progress.

One more question is with respect to negative mods. How that is handled in this recurrence relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To first understand the solution you need to know the following-**

A set subsets of set with i items(Say this set of subsets be **I**) is union of -

1)Subsets of set with i-1 items. Let this set of subsets be represented by **J**.

2)And all these subsets(of step 1) with union of ith element with them. Let this set of subsets be represented by **K**.

**Example** - Let items be [1, 2, 3]

Now, subsets of set with 2 items are - {}, {1}, {2}, {1,2}  which is **J**.

So, **K**={3}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}

**I = J + K**

**Lets move to your question now.**

Similar or you may call analogous to move method `dp[i][j]` ( or **I**) is sum of `dp[i-1][j]` ( or **J**) plus **K**.

**K** can be found  including ith element in **J** ie `dp[i-1][(j-a[i])%m]`. Now since we have included ith item than we need to add number for which sum will be required sum - value of ith item as it has been already included. This being the reason for using `(j-a[i])`.

How can be get absolute value - simply make a function that returns absolute value of given number and use it wherever you think you may need it.

Here's code for function-

```
int abs(int x){
     return x>0?x:-x;
}
```

Comment: you didn't answer my query as to how previous states are remembered for the example 6,7,7.

Comment: `dp[2][0]` we need to check if we get remainder is zero if last element is included. Now if this element is included to get zero remainder, so the sum of other elements(say s) should be such that `(s + 7) % 5 = 0` or `s + 7 = 5k` (ie it is multiple of 5)  which gives `s = 5k - 10 + 3` or `s = 5q +3`  ie we get 3 as remainder for sum of other elements. As a result `dp[1][3]` (when sum of other elements give remainder 3) needs  to be evaluated

Comment: exactly my point. dp[1][3] is not getting calculated with [*6*,*7*,7] previous indexes. If you could just explain me that, that would be great.

Comment: dp[1][3] **will** be calculated, though it may different thing that it may evaluate to zero

Comment: but then how is that right? How will that give us 1 as the result for dp[2][0?]

Comment: `dp[1][3]` is calculated when you loop `i` and `j` to their limits and evaluate `dp[i][j]` for each iteration. In your solution, i is iterated through zero to total no of items(ie is 0 to 2) and j for remainder ( ie 0 to 4) so in these loops there is an instance when `i=1` and `j=3` when dp[1][3] is evaluated (using sum of `dp[0][3]` and `dp[0][1]`).